# How to list nodes in ec2 west in libcloud

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, libcloud

I want to list nodes in ec2 region using [libcoud](http://libcloud.apache.org/).  How do I do that?  Below gives east only.

```
Driver = get_driver(Provider.EC2)
conn = Driver(key, secret)
conn.list_nodes()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the relevant driver for that region:

```
cls = get_driver(Provider.EC2_US_WEST)
driver = cls(ACCESS_ID, SECRET_KEY)
```

Taken from the bottom example in [this documentation page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/libcloud/docs/compute/examples.html?highlight=region).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the driver initialization.   For example:

```
ec2_conn = get_driver(Provider.EC2)(aws_key, aws_secret, region='us-west-1')
instances = ec2_conn.list_nodes(ex_node_ids=[i-xxxxxx])
print instances
```